# Trying to sort an array of objects alphabetically but Object can't be converted to String

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object

I am creating a hotel program which has an array filled with objects (Room), and each Room is filled with a customer name. I used an exchange sort to sort the array alphabetically, however I keep getting an error that Room cannot be converted into a String.
I am fairly new to Java and I am struggling to find a fix to this. This is my sort below. How could I overcome this issue?

```
private static void orderedView(Room hotelRef[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < hotelRef.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 12; j++) {

            if (hotelRef[i].compareTo(hotelRef[j]) > 0) {
                String temp;
                temp = hotelRef[i];
                hotelRef[i] = hotelRef[j];
                hotelRef[j]= temp;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Names in Sorted Order:");
    for (int i = 0; i < hotelRef.length - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println(hotelRef[i] + " ");

    }
    System.out.print(hotelRef[12 - 1]);

}
```

Comment: Can you show us more code please? Room would be useful.

Comment: temp is a Room not a string  this line of code is bad.  String temp;.  I would code.   Room mRoomTemp;   So I know the class by looking at the variable.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems here:

1. `if (hotelRef[i].compareTo(hotelRef[j])` this will work if `Room` implements [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) (or you have a custom `Room.compareTo`) that actually compares by customer name. If not then maybe you need:

   `if(hotelRef[i].getCustomerName().compareTo(hotelRef[j].getCustomerName()) > 0)`
2. `temp = hotelRef[i];`: `temp` is a String variable and you are trying to assing a `Room` to it. Change `String temp;` to `Room temp;`

If you are on Java-8 or above then you can sort it simpler using [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) and [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-):

```
Arrays.sort(hotelRef, Comparator.comparing(Room::getCustomerName));
// or whatever the customer name's getter method is named
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sort with the [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20int,%20int,%20java.util.Comparator))

for example:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, 0, arr.lenght, (Room lsh, Room rhs) -> {
   return lsh.getName().compareTo(rhs.getName());
});
```

Comment: Note that you can get the same comparator with less code: `Comparator.comparing(Room::getName)`, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

When coding Object Oriented Java, you need to create Getters and Setters for retrieving or modifying variables within an object. For example, you would make a function in Room similar to the following:

`public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }`

When you call this function on your object, it will return the customer name for you. I hope this helps, and good luck in your future excursions into Object Oriented Java.